# Firebase Analytics - Custom Event, see percentages instead of values (iOS)

Tags: ios, firebase, firebase-analytics

In my ios app, users upload files. I am logging a custom event called "upload_time" because I would like to see approximately how long uploads are taking.

```
  FIRAnalytics.logEvent(withName: "upload_time", parameters: [
                        kFIRParameterItemID: "upload_time_\(Constants.versionNumber)",
                        kFIRParameterItemName: val
  ])
```

I would like to be able to filter by the version number of the app and see the percentages of upload times. I have divided up times in 10s brackets so "val" is just rounded up to the nearest 10.

Just like how the select_content default event allows you to filter by content_type and then item_id, I would also like to be able to filter by version number and see the percentages for the different brackets of times in the console. At the moment, it seems that what I have setup is just adding up all the values for each day.

[How I setup parameters in the console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RWHzo.png)

Would greatly appreciate any help.

Comment: Consider [submitting this as a feature request](https://firebase.google.com/support/contact/bugs-features/)!

Answer (score 1):

There's no way to configure ad hoc reports in the Firebase console.

If you want reports other than those provided in the console, then your best bet here would be to [export the results to BigQuery](https://cloud.google.com/solutions/mobile/mobile-firebase-analytics-big-query) and [use a visualization tool](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/visualize-data-studio).

Once you have these set up, the sky is the limit :)

Answer (score 0):

[Firebase Performance Monitoring](https://firebase.google.com/docs/perf-mon/) sounds like a better fit if you're trying to measure upload times. Check out the getting started guide [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/perf-mon/get-started-ios). Performance Monitoring actually captures a bunch of network data automatically.

In addition, Performance Monitoring lets you filter by a number of parameters, such as device type, OS version, app version, and more. It's still in beta, so if there's some functionality that you'd like to have that isn't there yet, feel free to file a [feature request](https://firebase.google.com/support/contact/bugs-features/).

Answer (score 0):

To add another way to make this work in GA for Firebase is to [Export the Firebase data to Big Query](https://support.google.com/firebase/answer/6318765?hl=en&ref_topic=7029512) and run a query that calculates the percentage of upload time from all you app instances filtered by version.

Take a look at the Step 6 of this [doc](https://cloud.google.com/blog/big-data/2017/04/how-to-do-cross-platform-analytics-with-google-bigquery) on sample query for Big Query data gather by Firebase.